# useless CloudFoundry CLI color scheme on mac

Tags: color-scheme, cloud-foundry

I recently updated to CloudFoundry CLI 6.18.0* - since then the outputs have a "very hard to read" color scheme on my mac (OSX, El Capitan).

I know I can disable it with `CF_COLOR=false`, e.g.:

`CF_COLOR=false cf logs myapp`

But is there any way I can define a more user-friendly color scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next release (v6.21.0) will revert the color used in `cf help` (section headers) and `cf logs` that are hard to read on light colored terminal backgrounds back to what they were in v6.14.0 and before - Not an answer to how you can define a custom color scheme, but hopefully it takes away the need for that.

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to raise this as an issue in the CF CLI GitHub repo. Does this issue match what you are seeing?

[Unreadable text when using light background terminal](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/873)

If so, you can add a comment to that issue.